# How to remove the Drupal admin site notification messages?

Tags: drupal-7

I am new one for Drupal, I need to remove the notification messages in admin site.

the following notification messages always display in my drupal admin site:

> The content access permissions need to be rebuilt. Rebuild permissions.

Sometimes some more notification messages will come.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you wanna do that? What you see are system messages used to keep you informed of what is going on on the side and what are you doing. It is highly not encouraged at all to disable this feature.

Just in case you wonder how it is being printed out; It is being printed from page templates (e.g. `page.tpl.php` or `page--front.tpl.php`) via the variable `$messages`.

Comment: i am going to move the product to live, then my  client dont have a knowledge in drupal, if suppose he/she upgrade or click the notification message link means,i assume  it will affect the front end  .so i like to disable the feature

Comment: If `$messages` gets removed, then your client won't get any feedback upon node creation/editing/deleting or form submissions. Don't remove `$messages`, and try to solve website issues.